# Can the Lebesgue outer measure be characterized in terms of closed sets?

Tags: measure-theory, definition, lebesgue-measure

I'm wondering if the Lebesgue outer measure $\mu_*$ may be characterized as
$$\mu_*:S\mapsto \inf\left\{\mu(C):\text{for closed $C$ with } C\supseteq S \right\}.$$

---

The reason I ask is due to the following two equivalent characterizations of  $\mu_{*}:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)\to[0,\infty]$ (in the following $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, and a "$\sigma$-elementary set" is one which is the countable union of almost disjoint boxes):

1. Having defined $\mu$ on boxes, we define
   $$\mu_*:S\mapsto \inf\left\{\mu(E):\text{for $\sigma$-elementary $E$ with } E\supseteq S \right\}$$
2. Having defined $\mu$ on open sets, we define
   $$\mu_*:S\mapsto \inf\left\{\mu(U): \text{for open $U$ with } U\supseteq S\right\}$$

Comment: my guess is yes but is it really still $\inf$ and $S \subseteq C$ instead of reversing to $\sup$ and $S \supseteq C$ ? or...ah maybe my way is right, but you wanna ask about your way specifically because you saw an analogous thing where it's STILL $\inf$ and $\subseteq$ ?

Comment: @BCLC Well, I believe the _inner_ Lebesgue measure may be defined as $S\mapsto\sup\{\mu(C): \text{ for a closed $C$ with } C\subseteq S\}$. Yet that by itself does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: oh ok thanks for the info Sam. yeah i got nothing. very interesting question.

Comment: Wouldn't the set of rationals in $[0, 1]$ be a counterexample? This is countable, so has measure $0,$ therefore outer measure $0,$ but any closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ containing it must contain $[0, 1],$ and therefore have measure at least $1.$ But I've a horrible feeling I've misunderstood, so I'm only posting this as a comment!

Comment: @CalumGilhooley that _is_ a counterexample. Feel free to add that as an answer (:

Comment: I think it was the incorrect use of the symbol $\mu_*$ in the question that confused me. I was feeling a little groggy, and wasn't sure I was taking things in properly. It has been a year since I studied some measure theory, so I thought I must have forgotten more than I realised! I've corrected it to $\mu^*$ in my shiny new (and I hope correct!) answer. The symbol $\mu_*$ denotes inner measure.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley the use of $\mu^*$ (or $\mu_*$) confuses me as well; some authors use it to denote the outer measure, others the inner measure.

Comment: Thanks - that'll give me an excuse to browse through some textbooks in a relaxed way! It beats working. :)

Comment: @Sam Wait...can inner lebesgue measure be defined with open sets? Sounds like asking the same question then

Comment: @BCLC I've never seen the inner Lebesgue measure being defined with open sets; at this point I doubt it is possible, although if you know of such a characterization I would be very interested in learning aboout it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R},$ let $S = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1].$ Then $S$ is countable, so by a familiar argument (enclosing $S$ in a sequence of intervals of length $\epsilon/2^n$) it has Lebesgue outer measure $0.$ But $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R},$ so $\bar{S} = [0, 1].$ If $C$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $C \supseteq S,$ then $C \supseteq \bar{S} = [0, 1],$ therefore $\mu(C) \geqslant 1.$ Therefore:
$$
\mu^*(S) = 0 < 1 = \inf\left\{\mu(C):\text{for closed $C$ with } C\supseteq S \right\}.
$$
So the set $S$ provides a counterexample to the proposed criterion.